# How to make the MIUI navigation bar transparent in React Native app?

Tags: react-native, navbar, miui

I'm using @react-navigation/native for the navigation in the app, but when I switched to MIUI 12, I noticed that the MIUI navigation bar is overlapping my app navbar and this looks not so good:

[That's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoZqY.jpg)

I want this to look like this:

[That's how it supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mftIk.png)

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you should create native module *Immersive*, [Read About Immersive](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

OR you can try this [react-native-full-screen](https://github.com/Anthonyzou/react-native-full-screen). hope this is will be help